# Java: Custom BufferedImage / More than RGBA

Tags: java, awt, bufferedimage

I want to save not only Red, Green, Blue and Alpha in my Image.
Every pixel also needs Z-Depth information, like, how far it was away from the camera.
Furthermore, I need to display the Image in a JFrame,  so I can't use my custom Image class, but instead I need a BufferedImage or a subclass of it.
The Z-Depth shouldn't be visible in the JFrame. I just want to store it.

I've read much about the BufferedImage class. 
I assume that I will have to extend classes like SampleModel or ColorModel, but I can't figure out how that should be done.
A nice solution would be to instantiate a new BufferedImage but with a custom Pixelclass that also stores depth, without actually extending the BufferedImage.
But any solution and any idea will be appreciated!

**Does anybody know, which classes I have to extend, in order to save more information in every Pixel?**

Comment: It's possible to extra information in a `BufferedImage`, but I'm not sure it's of much use, if you want to display them in a `JFrame`. You will not be able to visualize your Z-index or depth in any way, without also implementing custom painting... Which kind of brings us back to... Why do you want to implement this as a `BufferedImage` in the first place. What is your ultimate goal or intention here? That's not very clear.

Comment: Thank you haraldK, I'm implementing a custom 3D render engine. Therefore, I only want to read / write the ZDepth, and I don't want it to be visualized. 
Previously, I used to have a BufferedImage for Color, and a float Array for depth. But the problem is that this Model is not very flexible and extensible. A Custom BufferedImage would be more elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I still don't understand why putting extra data into the `BufferedImage` would be more "flexible and extensible" in this case, so I'd probably just go with something like this myself:

```
public class DeepImage {
    private final BufferedImage image;
    private final float[] zIndex; // Must be image.width * image.height long

    // TODO: Constructors and accessors as needed...
}
```

But of course, you could put the Z-depth into a `BufferedImage`, if you really like to:

```
public class DeepBufferedImage extends BufferedImage {
    private final float[] zIndex;

    public DeepImage(final BufferedImage image, final float[] zIndex) {
        super(image.getColorModel(), image.getRaster(), image.getColorModel().isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);
        if (zIndex.length != image.getWidth() * image.getHeight()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("bad zIndex length");
        }
        this.zIndex = zIndex; // Obviously not safe, but we'll go for performance here
    }

    public float getZ(int x, int y) {...}; 
    public void setZ(int x, int y, float z) {...}; 

    public float[] getZ(int x, int y, int w, int h) {...}; 
    public void setZ(int x, int y, int w, int h, float[] z) {...}; 

}
```

The above class would work just like a normal `BufferedImage` for all cases, except it also happens to have a Z-index for each pixel.

Alternatively, you could make the Z-index part of the `DataBuffer`/`SampleModel`/`Raster`, but I think that would also require a custom `ColorModel` (or `ColorSpace`), and require quite a huge effort. These classes don't normally work well with "mixed" data types. Of course you could pack all your samples into one `long` per pixel, to avoid mixing data types:

```
long rgbaz = getRGB(x, y) << 32l | Float.toIntBits(getZ(x, y));
```

But, this would obviously kill performance.

So, in short, I just don't see the benefit from doing that. Especially as you don't want to visualize anything but the RGBA values, and there is also no file format I know of, that would support such a pixel layout*.

All of that said, there might still be a reason for you to implement this, I just don't see the need for it, given the requirements mentioned so far. Could of course be that I am missing something important. :-)

*) The TIFF format would support storing it, if you were using `float` samples for all 5 (R,G,B,A,Z) channels, or the packed `long` (64 bits) samples. However, I think it would be a lot simpler (and be a lot more compatible), to just store a normal 32 bit (8,8,8,8) RGBA image, and then a separate 1 channel `float` image in a multipage TIFF.

Comment: Thanks. That's not what I was expecting, but I feel that your work should be appreciated so I accepted it as the 'correct' answer.
I've had a similar class extending BufferedImage before, but it was very unflexible. I may have to store more Image data than just depth additionally. 
I currently have my custom Image class that holds an Array of Pixels, where Pixel is an Interface that one can implement. 
Thank you for you effort though :)

Comment: @Johannes Feel free to post your own solution too. Accept the one you think is the best/most correct. But upvote this answer if you found it useful. :-)

Comment: The Thing is: I knew that my solution worked, but I wanted the Speed of a BufferedImage because my own class is slow.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are looking for ImageComponent3D with allows you to define an 3D array of pixels.

> ImageComponent3D(int format, int width, int height, int depth) 
>              Constructs an 3D image component object using the specified format, width, height and depth.

[ImageComponent3D Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/java3d/forDevelopers/j3dapi/javax/media/j3d/ImageComponent3D.html)

Comment: Thank you, that's close to what I'm looking for, but I can't use that.
I am implementing my own 3D-Engine, so I don't want to use a class of a thirdparty 3D Application. If you know what I mean.

Comment: In that case you might need to use layered panes to layer objects and then capture depth with custom meta data.  It would be more work, but it would allow you to create your own 3D-Engine. [JLayeredPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html)

Comment: That sounds great! Can you please give me something that I can Google about that? Or  Event better, a source which does that?

Comment: Sure, here is a pretty simplistic 3D program walk through that demonstrates how to use it https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html